# All Pairs of 0 remove from NSString in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to remove all occurrence of 0 pairs before appearing any digit(1-9) from NSString

```
if 000001234000 required 01234000
if 0000123400  required 123400
if 012340000     required 012340000
if 00000012        required 12
```

Can anyone help ? thanks.

Comment: Have to try replacing @"00" with @"" ?

Comment: I have tried it but I dont know how many pairs of 0 in it

Comment: @Salim Number of pairs should not matter, `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00" withString:@""` will replace all pair of 0's in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution (but only trims ***leading*** '00'):

```
- (NSString *)trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:(NSString *)str {
    if (str.length > 1 ) {
        if ([[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] isEqualToString:@"00"]) {
            return [self trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:[str substringFromIndex:2]];
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Seems to work for your examples:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:@"000001234000"]);// returns 01234000
NSLog(@"%@", [self trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:@"0000123400"]);  // returns 123400
NSLog(@"%@", [self trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:@"012340000"]);   // returns 012340000
NSLog(@"%@", [self trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:@"00000012"]);    // returns 12
NSLog(@"%@", [self trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:@"12"]);          // returns 12
NSLog(@"%@", [self trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:@"02"]);          // returns 02
NSLog(@"%@", [self trimLeadingDoubleZerosFrom:@"2"]);           // returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *MyString = @"00000123050060007";
NSString *NewString = [self RemovePairOfZero:MyString];
NSLog(@"OUTPUT:: %@", NewString);


- (NSString *)RemovePairOfZero:(NSString *)Param
{
    if ([Param length] > 1 )
    {
        if ([[Param substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] isEqualToString:@"00"])
        {
            return [self RemovePairOfZero:[Param substringFromIndex:2]];
        }
    }
    return Param;
}


//2013-09-24 13:15:58.527 Test[1584:907] OUTPUT:: 0123050060007
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What can I do If I want 0123050060007.

Comment: Hmmm.  That edit on Sep 24 looks suspiciously like the answer I provided.

Comment: @SoOverIt : Sorry but I thing 2+1 always return 3. It doesn't matter how it's been wrote 2+1 or 1+2. Now you write 1+2 and I wrote 2+1 and if you say I just copied it from you then I have nothing to say....

Comment: @TapasPal It's not a huge deal, but looking at the [answer revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18959045/revisions), you changed your answer on the 24th to be the equivalent of what I wrote on the 23rd.  Just saying if you are going to *drastically* change your answer from your initial response to be the equivalent of an answer already provided, it would have been nice to point to that answer or acknowledge it.

Comment: @TapasPal I would also suggest that method names should generally start with a lowercase letter.  See the Typographic Conventions section in Apple's [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002931-BBCFHEAB)

Comment: @SoOverIt: Thank you for your kind information about the lowercase, but every one has their own style and for their style you can't deny them. You can see the [question was changed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18958832/revisions), and the [edited question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18958832/revisions) was totally differ from the [first one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18958832/revisions). and my initial answer was not going with the question so that I have to edit my answer.

Comment: @SoOverIt: Accidentally I have post my answer just after you that's why you are pull that issues about copy. Can you say just one thing If I was posted my answer before you, does it mean you have copied my answer??

Comment: @TapasPal: As I said, not a big deal.  Generally, if I'm providing a solution that is very similar to and already provided answer I make reference by saying 'as XYZ has suggested', etc.  That's just me.  Re method naming conventions, I would argue 1) StackOverflow is a teaching site, we should aim to follow best practices where possible 2) method naming has implications for your code (eg. Key-Value Coding Accessor Methods need to follow strict conventions).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* a = @"00000123";

while ([a hasPrefix:@"00"]) {

    a = [a stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2) withString:@""];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using stringByreplacingOccurancesOfString:@"00" withString:@""

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *s= @"00000123";

NSLog(@"%@",s);

s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00" withString:@"."];

NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

Try this one..

Answer (score -2):

That can be done by simply replacing @"00" with @""

```
NSString *string = @"00000123";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00" withString:@""];
```

Hope that helps!